# T-sql dynamically change function name that is within another function based on a paramater

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Is it possible to change name of a function that is called within another function based on a parameter? Under this text I have an example of a child function that (for specific language (english, german, etc.) converts minor currency into words based on the amount, for example if the amount was 1€, then it would convert it into "euro", and if it was 2€ then it would convert it into "euros".

```
/* HELP  
@number - number we use to determine whether we need to convert to singular/plural currency word  
@val - currency we need to convert  
@valsMap - table for currencies and their singular/plural name (id_val = currency for conversion, val_name = singular/plural word for the currency)  
@str - result of minor currency unit we've converted  
*/  
  
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test_secondPartInternal_ENG] (@number int, @val varchar(5))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS  
BEGIN  
--declare currency table  
DECLARE @valsMap TABLE (id_val NVARCHAR(5), val_name NVARCHAR(50))  
--declare string and set it's default value for conversion  
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''  
--insert currency and currency name  
INSERT INTO @valsMap (id_val, val_name) VALUES ('EUR', IIF(@number = 1, 'cent', 'cents')), ('CHF', IIF(@number = 1, 'centime', 'centimes'))
--set for currency  
 SET @str = @str + (SELECT val_name FROM @valsMap WHERE id_val = @val)  
--result of conversion  
RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@str))  
END
```

And here I have parent function that calls the above child function based on parameters that we have given (the above function exists for multiple languages), for example if we've set the @val paramater as "4" then it would call the above function which is for english.

```
/* HELP  
@number - number we need to convert  
@val - currency we need to convert  
@wordlang - language we need to convert to (1 HR, 2 RS, 3 SI, 4 ANG)  
@fnsMap - table for currencies and their functions (lang = language for conversion (1 HR, 2 RS, 3 SI, 4 ENG), fn_name = function name for specified currency)  
@str - result of minor currency unit we've converted  
*/  
  
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test_secondInternal] (@number INT, @wordlang INT, @val VARCHAR(3))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS  
BEGIN  
--declare currency table  
DECLARE @fnsMap TABLE (lang NVARCHAR(5), fn_name NVARCHAR(3))  
INSERT INTO @fnsMap (lang, fn_name) VALUES (1, 'HR'), (2, 'RS'), (3, 'SI'), (4, 'ENG')  
--declare string and set it's default value for conversion  
 DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''  
--set for function  
SET @str = @str + 'dbo.test_secondPartInternal_' + (SELECT fn_name FROM @fnsMap WHERE lang = @wordlang) + '(' + cast(@number as varchar(20)) + ', ''' + @val + ''')'  
--result of conversion  
 RETURN @str  
END
```

This is part that is used to call the previous function `SET @str = @str + 'dbo.test_secondPartInternal_' + (SELECT fn_name FROM @fnsMap WHERE lang = @wordlang)` based on the language that we have chosen and the result of the second function is a string "dbo.test_secondPartInternal_ENG(12, 'EUR')", which I can't convert within the same function to "euros" which would be the result of the conversion from the first function. So I'm wondering whether it is possible to change suffix of a function "test_secondPartInternal_" to for example "test_secondPartInternal_ENG" based on language we have chosen or can I only do it with "IF" statements?

Comment: You cannot execute dynamic sql in a function. The fact that you want to infers you have quite a large design flaw here, as needing to reference dynamic objects normally means a denormalisation issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at a single table that has `LanguageId`, `CurrencySymbol`, `CurrencyAbbreviation`, `MajorUnitSingular`, `MajorUnitPlural`, `MinorUnitSingular`, `MinorUnitPlural`, so that only a single lookup is needed. There may be additional information that is useful, e.g. `MajorMinorUnitMultiplier`, `ThousandsSeparator`, `DecimalSeparator`, ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I hadn't combined those 2 functions together is because the first one exists for multiple languages and so if I've put them all in one function, the code would've been too long, while they're sperate it's much faster to add or fix each function on its own. What I was trying to achieve is to template the call for the child function inside the parent function but it seems to be impossible. But together with my colleagues we've found a workaround for it. In the insert part code, instead of suffixes of the functions, I've put the full name of the each function so it works.
Instead of `INSERT INTO @fnsMap (lang, fn_name) VALUES (1, 'HR'), (2, 'RS'), (3, 'SI'), (4, 'ENG')`and `SET @str = @str + 'dbo.test_secondPartInternal_' + (SELECT fn_name FROM @fnsMap WHERE lang = @wordlang)` I've put the following `(1, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_HR(@number,@val)), (2, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_RS)), (3, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_SI)), (4, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_ENG))` and `SET @str = @str + (SELECT fn_name FROM @fnsMap WHERE lang = @wordlang)`

Final parent function looks like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test_secondInternal] (@number INT, @wordlang INT, @val VARCHAR(3))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS  
BEGIN  
--declare currency table  
DECLARE @fnsMap TABLE (lang NVARCHAR(5), fn_name VARCHAR(50))  
INSERT INTO @fnsMap (lang, fn_name) VALUES (1, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_HR(@number,@val)), (2, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_RS(@number,@val)), (3, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_SI(@number,@val)), (4, dbo.test_secondPartInternal_ENG(@number,@val)) 
--declare string and set it's default value for conversion  
 DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = ''  
--set for function  
SET @str = @str + (SELECT fn_name FROM @fnsMap WHERE lang = @wordlang)
 RETURN @str  
END
```

Edit: fixed some spelling errors and minor mistakes